# ContiguousArrayStoragePs9AnyObject issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, xcode7.3

What is that:

```
-[_TtGCs23_ContiguousArrayStoragePs9AnyObject__ dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x79b73b70
```

I got this log error message on the line of code:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(APCDeviceTableViewCell.reusableCellIdentifier(), forIndexPath: indexPath) as! APCDeviceTableViewCell
```

before everything worked perfect. but now Xcode started throw that issue.

Comment: `before everything worked perfect` Before what? Did you update Xcode, for example? Or made other modifications to your codebase?

Comment: @EricAya, I mean I just run Xcode one more time and now I have this error, program terminated with that log message.

Comment: @EricAya, looks like, clean and delete derived data helped me. also i reset simulator.

Comment: Ok. So, it's an issue that can't be reproduced, right? If cleaning Xcode's stale data solved it: no issue. :)